# Activate external href onclick from link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Let's say you have a link on your site and when you click that link it brings you to a different site. A site that you do not own and I would like it to have a "onclick" already activated maybe from a script that redirects to that link. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after.

Comment: for example lets say you click a link on my website that brings you to google and not only brings you there, it clicks an element like "search" or "I'm feeling lucky"

Comment: If the user is redirected to another site, the browser control is passed to that site. YOu'd have to wrap the external site in a frame. It should also be noted that if you're specifically targeting Google or similar, it's probably against their terms of service to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: Oh, OK, I see. I will look into that.

Comment: @Digitlworld uh I readed now your comment. Have you ever tried to call Google into an iframe? :)

Comment: @roXon nope. I've never had a legitimate reason to try. ;) That's why I indicated that it was likely against their TOS. (Sounds like Google actively blocks that behavior).

Comment: This sounds a bit shady - you're asking to send someone to another website, and then do a click for them?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021394/trigger-onclick-from-external-href

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer **NO**. If possible it would be called ***'mousejacking'*** :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `window.location.href` to a target link URL in javascript will, for most browsers, redirect the browser to the specified URL.

If you're specifically trying to make a link on your site redirect the user to a Google Search, read [here](http://www.blueglass.com/blog/google-search-url-parameters-query-string-anatomy/).

There is almost no *good* reason to wrap an external site that you do not own in a frame. That kind of stuff is usually considered shady/malicious.

Comment: and activate the onclick element?